# Q: R Torch memory usage on GPU for convolutional LSTM tutorial

Tags: r, pytorch

The [convolution LSTM tutorial linked from the Torch for R frontpage](https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2020-12-17-torch-convlstm/) is written to run on cpu by default -- no calls to a gpu device. I can set up and run it just fine.

When I make a GPU modification, as follows in the code below,

```
model <- convlstm(input_dim = 1, hidden_dims = c(64, 1), kernel_sizes = c(3,3), n_layers = 2)
#---CUDA modification
device <- if (cuda_is_available()) torch_device("cuda:0") else "cpu"
model <- model$to(device = device)
#---
optimizer <- optim_adam(model$parameters)
num_epochs <- 100

for (epoch in 1:num_epochs) {
  model$train()
  batch_losses <- c()
  for (b in enumerate(dl)) {
    optimizer$zero_grad()
    preds <- model(b$x$to(device = device))[[2]][[2]][[1]] #last time step output from the last layer
    loss <- nnf_mse_loss(preds, b$y$to(dtype = torch_float(), device = device))
    batch_losses <- c(batch_losses, loss$item())
    loss$backward()
    optimizer$step()
  }
  if(epoch %%10 ==0)
    cat(sprintf("\nEpoch %d, training loss: %3f\n", epoch, mean(batch_losses)))
}
```

I get 40-50 epochs in before encountering an obvious "your GPU outta memory," error:

```
Error in (function (self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)  : 
  CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 72.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 4.40 GiB already allocated; 10.19 MiB free; 4.74 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
Exception raised from malloc at ..\..\c10\cuda\CUDACachingAllocator.cpp:272 (most recent call first):
00007FFF51AFA7B200007FFF51AFA750 c10.dll!c10::Error::Error [<unknown file> @ <unknown line number>]
```

My GPU is pretty dated, a 2014-2015 GeForce GTX 970M, 3GB of memory native. But the tensors in this example are not particularly large. They're dim(100 6 1 24 24) synthetic tensors, although admittedly this structure is preserving all of the hidden and cell states. I don't have the background to calculate what this 'should' be using, but my intuition is that something about this setup (or the current R torch implementation) isn't cleaning up after itself, particularly through training epochs.

Is anyone able to either reproduce or easily run a GPU modification of my example, and is there a straightforward solution here or is there simply a fundamental limit to the capacity of my GPU in this case?